# Pyomo parameter estimation with time-varying input signals

Tags: python, optimization, estimation, pyomo

I want to try Pyomo for parameter estimation problems and this is what I have so far. First the parameters and variables are created. The unknows to the parameter estimation problem are `p1` to `p6`. The time-varying inputs are `TVL`, `mdot` and `TU`.

```
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.t = dae.ContinuousSet(initialize=time)

model.p1 = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals, initialize=5.993867814123688)
model.p2 = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals, initialize=0.5254928953213035)
model.p3 = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals, initialize=50.507139006670045)
model.p4 = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals, initialize=50.349545087852945)
model.p5 = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals, initialize=0.03248392142362977)
model.p6 = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals, initialize=0.10106006227941483)

model.TU = pyo.Param(model.t, default=273.15)
model.TVL = pyo.Param(model.t, default=333.15)
model.mdot = pyo.Param(model.t, default=0.01)

model.TR = pyo.Var(model.t)
model.TRL = pyo.Var(model.t)
model.TW = pyo.Var(model.t)

model.dTRdt = dae.DerivativeVar(model.TR, wrt=model.t)
model.dTRLdt = dae.DerivativeVar(model.TRL, wrt=model.t)
model.dTWdt = dae.DerivativeVar(model.TW, wrt=model.t)

model.t_meas = pyo.Set(within=model.t, initialize=time)
model.TR_meas = pyo.Param(model.t_meas, initialize=TR_dict)
```

The system consists of three ODEs.

```
def _diffeq1(model, t):
    return model.dTRdt[t] == model.p1 * (model.TRL[t] - model.TR[t]) - model.p2 * (model.TR[t] - model.TW[t])

def _diffeq2(model, t):
    return model.dTRLdt[t] == model.p3 * model.mdot[t] * (model.TVL[t] - model.TRL[t]) - model.p4 * (model.TRL[t] - model.TR[t])

def _diffeq3(model, t):
    return model.dTWdt[t] == model.p5 * (model.TR[t] - model.TW[t]) - model.p6 * (model.TW[t] - model.TU[t])

model.diffeq1 = pyo.Constraint(model.t, rule=_diffeq1)
model.diffeq2 = pyo.Constraint(model.t, rule=_diffeq2)
model.diffeq3 = pyo.Constraint(model.t, rule=_diffeq3)
```

This is the objective function.

```
def _obj(model):
    return sum((model.TR[i] - model.TR_meas[i])**2 for i in model.t_meas)
```

Simulation works fine according to the documentation

```
model.var_input = pyo.Suffix(direction=pyo.Suffix.LOCAL)
model.var_input[model.TU] = TU_dict
model.var_input[model.TVL] = TVL_dict
model.var_input[model.mdot] = mdot_dict

sim = dae.Simulator(model, package="casadi")
tsim, profiles = sim.simulate(numpoints=3600, integrator="cvodes", varying_inputs=model.var_input)
```

but I am having a hard time getting this to work with the optimization. Is there a recommended way to perform the optimization with time-varying inputs?

EDIT:

This is the code, I use for the optimization.

```
discretizer = pyo.TransformationFactory("dae.finite_difference")
discretizer.apply_to(model, wrt=model.t, nfe=200, scheme="BACKWARD")
solver = pyo.SolverFactory("ipopt")
results = solver.solve(model, tee=True)
```

I changed the above code from `model.TU = pyo.Var(model.t)` to `model.TU = pyo.Param(model.t, default=273.15)` (also for `TVL` and `mdot`). Otherwise ipopt tried to also find optimal trajectories for `TU`, `TVL` and `mdot`. With this new implementation only the default values are used for the optimization. I added the following figure showing `TU` to illustrate my point.

[image: problem]

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems with the model formulation. In order to optimize you have to discretize the model and call a solver. Could you include the code you're using for those steps?

Comment: I included the code used for the optimization.

Comment: How are you setting the initial conditions for your state variables `TR, TRL, and TW`?

Comment: Also, you might want to try solving the square problem using IPOPT, in other words solving the simulation using IPOPT. This can help you verify that you're getting the correct degrees of freedom when moving from simulation to optimization.

Comment: The states are initialized using e.g. `model.TR[0].fix(293.15)`. I found a solution to my problem adding additional constraints containing the time-varying inputs, but I don't think this is a very good approach. The time spent on the optimization is significantly longer than in Matlab.